# jquery dialog fire open event twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a problem with jquery-ui.

I bind a click event to open a dialog, but the dialog's open function fires twice.

The click event only fires once, is only the open function that opens two dialog

This is my code:

```
<div id="modalWindow">Cargando...</div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var ventana = $("DIV#modalWindow");
            ventana.dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                show: "slow",
                hide: "slow",
                width: 500,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                modal: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                Ok: function () { $(this).dialog("close").html("Cargando..."); },
                close: function () { $(this).html("Cargando..."); }
            });

            $("DIV.imagen_perfil img").click(function (evt) {
                //...some code
                    ventana.dialog({
                        title: "Subir Imagen",
                        open: function (event, ui) {
                            //...loads PartialView
                        }
                    });
                ventana.dialog("open");
            });

        });
        </script>
```

This is the HTML that fires the click event:

```
<li>
    <label >Imagen de perfil:(Click en la Imagen Para Agregar):</label>
    <div class="imagen_perfil">
        <img src="~/images/imagen_pordefecto.png"/>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are calling the `dialog` function again in the click (which triggers the first `open`call, the second is your actual call to `open`), If you can ommit the dialog function, that solves the problem, if you really have to change information about the dialog, you should use the `option` method (instead of calling `dialog`again)

```
ventana.dialog( "option", { title: 'New Title',open:function(){...} } );
```